# Why is that this way

Tags: differences, american-english

I realized all of a sudden that I don't understand why it works like this:

> Your rope is going to tear!

And

> Your rope is going to be torn!

In the first case to me it seems like the rope is going to tear something or somebody.

The second one I just feel doesn't sound natural, so I'm confused.

Which one is right and why?

Comment: Ropes don't generally 'tear'; they **break**. You rope is going to break. We can use verbs of action about objects, as if the object did the action - a rope breaks, a car stops, a potato cooks.

Comment: *Tear* can be transitive or intransitive.

Comment: See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I'll switch to what I consider a better example. _The toast is going to burn [unless you remove the grill pan right away]._ // _The toast is going to be burnt  [unless you remove the grill pan right away]._ These are acceptable paraphrases, the first using the causative-ergative alternation (cf 'the window broke') whereas the second uses the passive (cf 'the window was broken [by the golf ball]); but your examples are set in a future timeframe.

Comment: What @Kris said. But note that ***to tear / to be torn*** and ***to burn / to be burnt*** mean pretty much the same thing, whereas with other verbs that's not the case. There's a huge difference between ***We're going to see / We're going to be seen***, for example.

Comment: @FF It perhaps doesn't get much bigger than with  _We're going to eat_....

Comment: The first conveys the action happening in the future.  The second conveys the action being in the past in the future.

Comment: It is just that there are verbs we should use in active voice, and certain others in passive.   Some verbs can be used as both, like a) To break the glass...(PV...the glass to be broken) b) to tear the paper; (the paper to be torn). The same verbs are also used as intransitives (where PV is not possible), like 'The glass breaks.... (by itself) where one can't use PV.

Comment: @Ram Pillai No, it's not so simple. 'He drinks the wine': active voice. /  'The wine is drunk [by him]': passive voice. // 'This wine drinks well' is not usually considered to be another active construction (obviously, the verb is still the same lexeme here, not a homograph), but a 'middle voice' construction. 'The rope tore' / 'the glass broke' are very similar ergative constructions.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Your rope is going to tear!

And

> 2) Your rope is going to be torn!
>
> In the first case to me it seems like the rope is going to tear something or somebody. In the second one I just feel doesn't sound natural.
>
> Which one is right and why?

---

The first one as it stands is correct, although I would say that to my ear (note I am British) the use of tear connected with rope sounds strange. Normally we would use Break.

> **Your rope is going to tear!**

meaning

**Your rope** [noun], **is, go-ing** [verb] (HAPPEN-ing), **to,  be pulled apart**

---

The second one I agree doesn't sound natural, it has something missing.

> Your rope is going to be torn.

However I think this works much better.

> **Your rope is going to be torn apart**

Example [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/apart)

> Concerns that moral fabric and cohesiveness of society will be **torn apart** provide reasons for care and reflection.

However why tear/torn should sound strange is a little bit of a mystery. I would suggest that there is a reason albeit a subtle connection. Which is made clear when you substitute the noun.

Your jacket is going to be torn

Your hand is going to be torn (to bits).

Your family is going to be torn (apart)

Your newspaper is going to be torn

Your photo is going to be torn (out)

Tear/Torn is often used alongside another verb, torn apart. torn to pieces, torn to bits, torn to ribbons, to shreds etc the [Cambridge Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/breaking-and-damaging/tearing-and-breaking-into-pieces/)  lists many relate words.

Answer (score 0):

I think both could be correct:

"Your rope is going to break!"

(I agree I would not use 'tear' with a rope - tear is more applicable to a sheet, of fabric or paper...)

This phrase could be said as a warning if one rock climber had seen his friend's rope starting to fray (fibres begin to break) after rubbing on a sharp rock.

"Your rope is going to be broken!" is an unusual use of English, in that it is not complete...

This phrase is less urgent than the first and could be used to express a predicted future event, for example:  "Your rope is going to be broken [torn] by the sharp rocks!"

However, it would probably not be used in this form as, on its own, it does not give enough information. It would probably be used with an 'IF' statement, something like:

"If you hang your rope over that edge, it will break [*because the sharp rock edge will cut through it...*]"